# Telnet output parsing

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm now trying to work with telnetlib in Python 3.4.
All I want is to try send command to my access point and get some response.
My code:

```
`import telnetlib
 import time

 user='admin'
 password='admin'
 host='192.168.1.1'


 try:
    tn=telnetlib.Telnet("host")
    tn.read_until(b"Login: ")
    tn.write(user.encode() + "\r\n".encode())
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode() + "\r\n".encode())
    print("Connection establised")
 except Exception:
    print("Connection failed")

 cmd="interface AccessPoint\r\n"
 tn.write(cmd.encode())
 cmd2="ssid TEST\r\n"
 tn.write(cmd2.encode())

 output=n.read_eager()
 while output:
    print(output.decode())
    time.sleep(.2)
    output=tn.read_eager()
```

`
For example, this script should change name of the SSID to TEST.
Then I'm doing it in Putty, it's fine:
[image]

But then I'm trying to read response from my script, I see smth like that:

[image]

Please, tell me what does all these symbols mean?
Is there way to cut them all from my logs?

P.S. Tried all other ways of reading, like read_all. Tried without decode(), tried with decode('utf-8'), but symbols were here always. What else should I do?

Thank you, Mairy.

Comment: You don't need `\`` *and* block indentation in your question. Use backticks for in-line code, use indentation for multi-line blocks of code. An easy way to indent a large block of code is to select it all and press `{}` in the toolbar above the text editor.

Comment: Thank you, will do it better next time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access point believes it is talking to a terminal emulator. Those symbols are so-called "ANSI Escape Codes," after the now-withdrawn standard ANSI X3.64.

The string `Escape`-`[`-`K` means "erase to end of line." The string `Escape` - `[` - `1` - `6` - `D` means "move the cursor 16 spaces to the left."

- You could convince your access point that it isn't talking to a terminal emulator, or that it is talking to a non-ANSI terminal emulator, or
- You can erase them from your logged strings by using an appropriate regular expression such as `msg = re.sub('\x1b\\[\\d*[A-Z]', '', msg)`

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code